# Joule-Thomson and heat exchanger combination

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose a refrigerant (say propane) at pressure P1 and temperature T1 in two different set ups (as shown in the diagram below):

#1:  The refrigerant passes through a Joule-Thomson valve and exists at pressure P2 and temperature T2.

#2:  The refrigerant first flows through a heat exchanger and its temperature drops, then flows through the Joule-Thomson valve and finally passes through the heat exchanger, exchanging heat with warm stream. It exists the exchanger at pressure P2 and temperature T3. (Note the exit pressure is P2, same exit pressure in #1).

Can we say T3 is always greater than T2?

Suppose friction loss in pipes and exchanger is negligible and heat is no heat transfer with the environment.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "what can we say T3 is always greater than T2?"

Comment: @Al Nejati Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system contains a pure component refrigerant, which is the usual case for refrigeration systems.  The boiling temperature of a pure component is strictly dependent on the pressure that the pure component experiences, as given by the Antoine equation, seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_equation).

For case 1, a high temperature (T1), high pressure (P1) refrigerant goes through an expansion valve, where there is substantial pressure drop due to the refrigerant running through a restriction at a relatively high flow rate.  This pressure drop causes the high temperature liquid to boil, and the heat required for boiling comes from the refrigerant itself, causing its temperature to drop dramatically.  When the refrigerant reaches pressure P2, it is a mixture of cold vapor and cold liquid (e.g., 10% vapor and 90% liquid) whose temperature (T2) depends strictly on its ambient pressure.

For case 2, the diagram shows heat exchange between the high temperature refrigerant entering the expansion valve and the low temperature liquid and vapor exiting the expansion valve.  By cooling off stream 1, its lower temperature entering the expansion valve means that there is less heat available to boil the refrigerant as it enters the expansion valve.  In addition, the heat exchange from the hot refrigerant to the cold refrigerant means that some of the cold refrigerant is boiled in the heat exchanger.  Due to conservation of energy, the net effect should be the same amount of cold liquid and cold vapor downstream of the heat exchanger as was seen downstream of the expansion valve in case 1, meaning that you are wasting the cost of a heat exchanger in case 2 (you don't get any "gain" from that heat exchanger).

Regarding temperature T3, the refrigerant exits the heat exchanger at pressure P2, just as it did in case 1.  Because the exit pressure is the same in both cases, the exit temperatures are the same in both cases, which means that T2 = T3.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics to the overall system in each case, then, for each  case, you get $\Delta h=0$.  From this it follows that the enthalpy at point 2 in both cases is the same, and so also must also be the temperature T2.